# Invoke on Control vs. Invoke on Form

Tags: c#, multithreading, ui-thread

For example I use the following code:

```
private void startCalculcationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(this.numberTextBox.Text, out number)) {
    this.calculationResultLabel.Text = "(computing)";
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            int result = LongCalculation(number);
            this.calculationResultLabel.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => {
                this.calculationResultLabel.Text = result.ToString();
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

There I call `this.calculationResultLabel.BeginInvoke(...)` to switch to the UI-Thread for setting the Result to the Label.

I could also use `this.Invoke(...)` (this is the Form). Does it make a difference internally?

Comment: It makes no difference.  A reference to the form or the control is needed by the runtime to figure out which thread owns it.  The Handle property is the important one.   A form cannot contain a control that was created on a different thread, so either is good enough.  Note that you have a threading race bug in this code, there is no obvious way you can ensure that the form was not closed by the user when this code runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Invoke on Control vs. Invoke on Form
>
> I could also use this.Invoke(...) (this is the Form). Does it make a difference internally?

It sounds like you are asking two different things.  Your title says `Invoke` **but your code** is using `BeginInvoke` but you seem to be also asking about whether to invoke on a form or control.

1. It makes no difference whether you `xxxInvoke` to the form or a specific control.  Both are UI elements and both can marshal calls for you.
2. If you are asking about the difference between `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke`, two methods that can marshal a call to the UI thread via the message pump, there is a difference between them. `Invoke` can lead to thread deadlock whilst the latter won't.

Anyway, since you are using `Task` and that you update the UI immediately after the long running task, you are arguably better doing:

```
private void startCalculcationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(this.numberTextBox.Text, out number)) 
    {
        this.calculationResultLabel.Text = "(computing)"; // UI thread
        var result  = await Task.Run(() => 
                LongCalculation(number));  // threadpool thread

        calculationResultLabel.Text = result.ToString(); // UI thread
    }
}
```

No fiddly manual marshalling required via `BeginInvoke` or dangerous-to-use `Invoke`.